# Execute AT commands in J2ME

Tags: java-me, at-command

I want to know how to execute AT commands inside a J2ME application. The approach that I am taking in brief is as below:

First get all the ports that are present in the phone by

`String ports = System.getProperty("microedition.commports");`

Now just try to write "AT" and wait for the response from each port (YES I said **EACH**!!!)

```
try{
  commConnection = (CommConnection) Connector.open("comm:" + portsArr[i] + ";baudrate=19200");
} catch (IOException e) {
    print("IOException:Port:" + portsArr[i] + "~Mess: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Once I get an "OK" from some port I can execute my intended commands in the same way.

I am trying to execute this on two diffrent phones

[Nokia SuperNova 7210](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_7210_supernova-2447.php)

ports=USB1

When I try to write to the port nothing happens.

[Nokia Xpress music](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_5233-3390.php)

ports= USB2,COM1,IR1,USB1,BT1,BT2,BT3,BT4,BT5,BT6,BT7,BT8,BT9,BT10,BT11,BT12,BT13,BT14,BT15,BT16,BT17,BT18,BT19,BT20,BT21,BT22,BT23,BT24,BT25,BT26,BT27,BT28,BT29,BT30,BT31,BT32,BT33,BT34,BT35,BT36,BT37,BT38,BT39,BT40,BT41,BT42,BT43,BT44,BT45,BT46,BT47,BT48,BT49,BT50,BT51,BT52,BT53,BT54,BT55,BT56,BT57,BT58,BT59,BT60,BT61,BT62,BT63,BT64

When I try to write to USB2,COM1,BT1 port

```
IOException:Port:COM1~Mess: SymbianOS error = -1 : General:
System error
IOException:Port:USB1~Mess: SymbianOS error = -21 : General:
System error
IOException:Port:BT1~Mess: SymbianOS error = -44 : General:
System error
```

Is this a correct approach?

[Smslib](http://code.google.com/p/smslib/) uses AT commands but I'm not understanding how do they execute AT commands or how they get the port on which to write the AT commands?

If not possible with J2ME I don't mind not writing the execution of AT commands in some other language as long as both are able to communicate and the solution will support a most of the vendors.

Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803508/can-i-use-at-commands-insider-j2me-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is absolutely **not possible**.

Your approach would only work if Java ME provided access to the GSM modem via COMM ports, which it does not!

(I suppose there *could* possibly be a device somewhere which offers this, anything's possible in Java ME land, but I have never seen or heard of this).

The library you are referring to runs on a PC which has a device connected to it via the COMM port, it does **not** work in a Java ME context.

I suspect that what you're really trying to do is access the handset's native SMS inbox via a MIDlet.  I promise you, there is **absolutely no way** to do this!

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is just send an SMS, maybe you can get to it using an APDU. It seems technically possible:

First you will need JSR 177 SATSA-APDU. Check Nokia devices that have support for it at http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Java_ME_API_support_on_Nokia_devices

Then you will have to create an SMS APDU just like an STK Applet would do. Please check "Sending a message in the PDU mode" at http://www.dreamfabric.com/sms/

I did not try this, but this is the path I would go if I had to. If it does work with you, please share.